# Use own custom form with MailChimp

Tags: html, forms, customization, mailchimp

I'm currently working on a  "coming soon" page that has a single text field and button where a user can input his/her email address to get notified when the app launches. I've heard that mailchimp is quite a nice little tool to use that handles all the user details that gets collected (meaning I don't have to worry about any scripting and a database my side) as well as automatically emailing the user that signed up thanking them etc.

I've tried designing a form to use on my site with mailchimp but I'm just not happy with the overall look and feel of the forms. Sure I can change edit some properties like color and all that jazz, but it just doesn't fit my needs.

Is there a way that I can use my current html form that I already have, with mailchimp? Instead of using the forms that one designs on mailchimp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not mailchimp support

Answer (score 8):

You bet.

I'd check out their support article about [custom hosted forms](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-host-my-own-sign-up-forms). It explains a bit about how form fields will need to look to jive with their database. You could also view-source of the mailchimp-hosted form you designed and see how the input names/types are put together there specifically for your list.

Also, paid accounts can use [advanced forms mode](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/advanced-customization-of-mailchimps-sign-up-forms) to customize the HTML that they host for a list.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as winfred mentionned there are several ways.

If you know html, just get the code from the subscription html page (through "View Source" for example) and paste into a blank html page that you can modify before uploading to your website.

As you just need the email, this should be straight forward.

If you haven't seen it yet, this page could help:
http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-host-my-own-sign-up-forms

Good Luck!